# what ebay api can I use for getting buyer feedback(check whether buyer leaves feedback)?

Tags: php, ebay-api

I spent a long time on finding which ebay api I can use for getting buyer feedback, but have no luck. I attached a picture below to show what data I would like to get:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXLjM.png)

Just like the image above. I have already gotten my(seller) feedback message by using "[GetFeedback](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetFeedback.html)" Ebay API. However, I didn't find any element for me to get customer(buyer) product feedback.

I also checked "GetOrders" API. It doesn't support feedback checking neither.

So, my question is: does anyone know which ebay API method I can use for getting buyer's feedback message or feedback status(left or not)? Or any other thing that relative to this part.

**Update:**

According to @Oleksandr Otchenashev answer, I finally found a way to check whether my buyers left me feedback or not. `FeedbackDetailArray->FeedbackDetail->CommentingUser` returns me the user who left the feedback. Based on these username, I will know if I left feedback to my client or they left me any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [GetFeedback api](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetFeedback.html) is the correct way to receive feedbacks.

Please take a look at field [FeedbackType](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/FeedbackTypeCodeType.html) in the api cal.

> **FeedbackLeft**
>   (in) This enumeration value will be used in the FeedbackType field of a GetFeedback call if the user wants to retrieve the Feedback they have left for their order partners while acting as a seller or buyer.
>
> **FeedbackReceived**
>   (in) This enumeration value will be used in the FeedbackType field of a GetFeedback call if the user wants to retrieve the Feedback data that they have received acting as a seller and buyer.

Another part that could be interested is a [Role](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/TradingRoleCodeType.html) in response.

Both of this two fields allow you understand is it feedback left for me as a seller by a buyer. Or this is my feedback as a buyer role left for another seller.

So you can do two calls for feedback api, first to get "FeedbackReceivedAsSeller" and second as "FeedbackLeft"

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Sorry that I have another question: what field I can use for displaying the feedback message? I tried [FeedbackDetailArray->FeedbackDetail->FeedbackResponse](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetFeedback.html#Response.FeedbackDetailArray.FeedbackDetail.FeedbackResponse), but didn't get any message.

Comment: I found [FeedbackDetailArray->FeedbackDetail->FeedbackResponse](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetFeedback.html#Response.FeedbackDetailArray.FeedbackDetail.FeedbackResponse) is not the correct field I need. However, I still have no idea which field I need to use for showing the received feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I found out the solution. `FeedbackDetailArray->FeedbackDetail->CommentingUser` can provide me the name of the user, who leave the feedback. `FeedbackDetailArray->FeedbackDetail->CommentText` will provide me the feedback content.

Comment: Yes, you right. CommentText is exactly feedback data. You always can test GetFeedback feature in ebay sandbox. There a list of already created users https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=226, some of the users have a lot of feedbacks.